# How to extract mutiple .zip.part files where one of the files is a .bin

Tags: files, extract

Hope somehow can help me with this situation:
For an installation of a program I have about 10 .zip.part files. In every zip.part file is another .rar file. In the first .zip.part there is a .rar file which contains a .bin file.

So far I have figured out I need to run the .bin to get the installation going. Only thing is I can't figure out how to get it running. I already tried to join the .zip.part files to a new zip file with the cat file1.zip.part file2.zip.part etc.zip.part > complete.zip, but somehow this command only shows one of the numerous files beeing extracted (for example: only file6.rar is shown).

Can anyone tell me how I can get the .bin file running (extracting the .bin file manually gives an error)

Comment: What do you mean by _"but somehow this command only shows one of the numerous files beeing extracted"_? Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/523980/edit) your question and explain exactly what happens when you unzip `complete.zip`. Also, my first advice in a situation like this would be: check with whoever provided you with this set of installation files. It's hard to believe they didn't come with any kind of installation instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I belive you have tu unzip the first of the .parts file and it will get the subsecuents ones if needed. 
Then unrar the .rar files produced and finally excecute the .bin install.